# php - smtp server

Tags: php

I am working on a project. For that i have downloaded smtp server on ubuntu. Could any one please tell me the command to check whether the smtp server install properly or not. because email is not getting generated.

**Below is the code for your reference**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

include('config.php');

// table name
$tbl_name="temp_members_db";

// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

// Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="FROM: your email";

// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
//$message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
$message.="http://localhost/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

// send email   
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}

// if not found
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check. Is it listening on the standard SMTP port 25 ? (e.g. `telnet localhost 25` - does this connect?)

Second check. What do the log files say ? The doc should indicate where those logs are (`/var/log` perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

Check if sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart gives errors, change postfix to mail server that you installed.